# Writing a GET request to return HTTP 1.1 instead of 1.0

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm writing a tcp web client and web server in python (and I'm new to python and sockets/networking). Everything is working but I'd like to implement the HTTP/1.1 protocol rather than HTTP/1.0 and I can't get a response of 1.1 no matter what I do. I read that it requires a host field, but maybe I'm doing something else wrong.

Here is my GET request

```
request = "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\nHost: " + HOST + "\r\n\r\n"
```

Here is my response

```
"b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

I'm using BaseHTTPRequestHandler for my web server.  Is that the problem maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the [`protocol_version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.protocol_version) to `'HTTP/1.1'` in your `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` implementation:

> `protocol_version`
> This specifies the HTTP protocol version used in responses. If set to `'HTTP/1.1'`, the server will permit HTTP persistent connections; however, your server must then include an accurate `Content-Length` header (using `send_header()`) in all of its responses to clients. For backwards compatibility, the setting defaults to `'HTTP/1.0'`.